# how can I calm down my scared cat?

Tags: cats

Ever since my cat woke up from a loud noise of a heavy plank falling, his been acting too scared of almost any sound be it just a piece of paper moving or plastic raper sound or even a dried leaf on the floor!!! He calms down a bit when I pat him or lay down with him, but later its the same.

Actually this has happened before about two months ago too, but he became normal later say in nearly a week!!

I asked the vet for any medicine for anxiety or fear but he told me there is no such thing...and told me to stay with Nayla to calm him.

So I tried homeopathy, Kali phos and argentum nitrum 30, both seems to worked last time.

Does anyone know the reason or how I can make him understand that its OK even when he is alone !

Comment: I wouldn't bother with the homeopathy, it won't hurt the cat (since it's just water) but it won't do anything to help him either (since it's just water).

Comment: Xanax (alprazolam) is a mild tranquilizer commonly used in humans, cats and dogs. There are special low-dose prescriptions for animals so never give them human doses. Sometimes xanax is prescribed to cats with anxiety disorders and is also used to calm animals when going on airplane or train trips. I don’t know if i would use Xanax in your situation, but if you think the quality of your cat’s life would be improved with some relaxation then i would say go for it. Alternately you could try sone catnip.

Answer (score 1):

Some cats are naturally very skittish. My cat will freak out from loud talking (not yelling, just talking a bit loudly), people laughing, or even people just walking around more than she likes.

When she gets scared, she seeks out one of her hiding spots to hide in and reassure herself. So give your cat places that it can hide in, preferably places that are small enough that a person couldn't get in there easily. Like a small closet, the nook inside cat trees, behind or under furniture, and so forth.

When your cat is in a hiding spot, don't bother it. Just let it naturally come out on its own. Ignore it and do something else, quietly. If the cat sees you're waiting for it just outside its hiding spot, it may feel cornered and parodoxically it'll take even longer to get it to come out.

Comment: It should be worth noting that for this kind of skittishness acknowledging it is validating it in the eyes of the pet, basically saying "I know something bad happened, but it's alright now" which reinforces the behaviour. Soothing a pet that is scared is fine when the cause really is something that should be scary. However for something like dried leaves or such you should react towards the cat more like their behaviour is unexpected, not like the reaction is natural or expected.

Comment: Yeah he is 2 yrs old and he had no issues with loud sound or even fire crackers sounds to some point...this is very unusual of him to be so scared...that's the reason I have posted this question here

Comment: It happend only after the loud bang sound of the plank falling while he was in deep sleep